# Sort_value wrong descend

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'dont know what's wrong with my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
woe = [1.1147295474833758,0.364043491078754,-0.05525053172192353,-0.3950007109750665,-0.6784658191115104,-0.9522135140050229,-1.1441658353033486]
iv = [0.29078213954085946,0.29078213954085946,0.29078213954085946,0.29078213954085946,0.29078213954085946,0.29078213954085946,0.29078213954085946]
lis = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
fin = [lis,woe,iv]
fin = np.array(fin).T  
df_disc = pd.DataFrame(fin,columns=['Label','WoE','IV'])
print(df_disc)
df_disc = df_disc.sort_values(by=['WoE'])
df_disc = df_disc.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_disc)
```

result

```
  Label                   WoE                   IV
0     A    1.1147295474833758  0.29078213954085946
1     B     0.364043491078754  0.29078213954085946
2     C  -0.05525053172192353  0.29078213954085946
3     D   -0.3950007109750665  0.29078213954085946
4     E   -0.6784658191115104  0.29078213954085946
5     F   -0.9522135140050229  0.29078213954085946
6     G   -1.1441658353033486  0.29078213954085946
  Label                   WoE                   IV
0     C  -0.05525053172192353  0.29078213954085946
1     D   -0.3950007109750665  0.29078213954085946
2     E   -0.6784658191115104  0.29078213954085946
3     F   -0.9522135140050229  0.29078213954085946
4     G   -1.1441658353033486  0.29078213954085946
5     B     0.364043491078754  0.29078213954085946
6     A    1.1147295474833758  0.29078213954085946
```

i think the correct ones would be label G,F,E,D,C,B,A but the result seems wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your DataFrame, column is filled by objects, not numeric.

In code if convert strings and numeric values all values are converted to objects:

```
fin = np.array(fin).T
```

Solution is use dictionary by columns names and pass to [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df_disc = (pd.DataFrame(fin,columns=['Label','WoE','IV'])
             .astype({'WoE':'float', 'IV':'float'}))
print(df_disc)

df_disc = df_disc.sort_values(by=['WoE'], ignore_index=True)
print(df_disc)
  Label       WoE        IV
0     G -1.144166  0.290782
1     F -0.952214  0.290782
2     E -0.678466  0.290782
3     D -0.395001  0.290782
4     C -0.055251  0.290782
5     B  0.364043  0.290782
6     A  1.114730  0.290782
```

You can prevent it if pass dictionaries to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df_disc = pd.DataFrame({'Label':lis,'WoE':woe,'IV':iv})
print(df_disc)
    
df_disc = df_disc.sort_values(by=['WoE'], ignore_index=True)
print(df_disc)
  Label       WoE        IV
0     G -1.144166  0.290782
1     F -0.952214  0.290782
2     E -0.678466  0.290782
3     D -0.395001  0.290782
4     C -0.055251  0.290782
5     B  0.364043  0.290782
6     A  1.114730  0.290782
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated, the column contains strings. To preserve the precision, convert the Series to `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

# ...

df_disc['WoE'] = df_disc['WoE'].apply(Decimal)
df_disc = df_disc.sort_values(by='WoE')
print(df_disc)
```

Prints:

```
  Label                   WoE                   IV
6     G   -1.1441658353033486  0.29078213954085946
5     F   -0.9522135140050229  0.29078213954085946
4     E   -0.6784658191115104  0.29078213954085946
3     D   -0.3950007109750665  0.29078213954085946
2     C  -0.05525053172192353  0.29078213954085946
1     B     0.364043491078754  0.29078213954085946
0     A    1.1147295474833758  0.29078213954085946
```

Answer (score 2):

Your columns `WoE` and `IV` are of `dtype` `object`. Need to convert it to `float` for correct `sort`:

```
In [2723]: df_disc.dtypes
Out[2723]: 
Label    object
WoE      object
IV       object
dtype: object

In [2725]: df_disc.WoE = df_disc.WoE.astype(float)

In [2726]: df_disc.sort_values(by=['WoE'])
Out[2726]: 
  Label       WoE                   IV
6     G -1.144166  0.29078213954085946
5     F -0.952214  0.29078213954085946
4     E -0.678466  0.29078213954085946
3     D -0.395001  0.29078213954085946
2     C -0.055251  0.29078213954085946
1     B  0.364043  0.29078213954085946
0     A  1.114730  0.29078213954085946
```